# Including chmod in shell script - will it work for everyone?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, unix, chmod

I have a large `wrapper.sh` file which does a lot of things, but in the end runs `catalina.sh` tomcat.

Problem is that users who run this `wrapper.sh` are experiencing error: no permissions to execute `catalina.sh`. They have to manually set this permission, which is something I do not want.

---

On my computer, `chmod u+x catalina.sh` fixes this, therefore I included it in the `wrapper.sh`, right before executing `catalina.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# <...>
# <...>
chmod +x catalina.sh
exec ./catalina.sh
```

But will this change work for everyone? I can imagine, for example, that it indeed works fine on my computer, but someone else would get some sudo-related error when implicitly running that `chmod`. How can I make it work for everyone?

Answer (score 4):

How about running it instead by `sh catalina.sh` or `bash catalina.sh` (depending on what language that script is written in)? In this case, you don't need x-permission. Read permission is enough.

Answer (score 2):

It will work if the user is root, or else the owner of `catalina.sh`.

An unprivileged user cannot change the permissions on a file that the user does not own, even if it is writable.

If `catalina.sh` is something that the same user unpacked, or that your script created, there shouldn't be a problem.

The one issue might be that the user is trying to do this in a filesystem that is mounted `noexec`. But then the `wrapper.sh` script itself wouldn't be executable. Yet, the user could successfully run `sh wrapper.sh` in spite of it not being executable, and then run into the `catalina.sh` problem.

Note that you can `exec sh ./catalina.sh`. Just because the script not executable doesn't mean you cannot exec a new process image for the interpreter to process it; you just have to do it explicitly rather than relying on the operating system to bind the interpreter to the script. That is what requires execute permissions.

Comment: If `catalina.sh` is a shell script, like the name suggests, you can always `sh catalina.sh` -- you only need read access for that. (Shell scripts should not have extensions, generally speaking; and if it's not a `sh` script, use whichever shell you need. Commonly beginners confusingly use `.sh` for e.g. Bash scripts, too.)

Answer (score 0):

- Create a user group "sudo groupadd new_group".
- Add the users who need access to
  this group: "sudo usermod -a -G new_group userA" for a single user, or: "for user in userA userB userC; do sudo usermod -a -G mygroup "$user"; done" to add multiple users with a loop.
- Then "sudo chown somebody:new_group catalina.sh"